# I am trying to build this table, but since I am new to LaTex I really need help. I want the table to fit in the page and also look as the one below

Tags: tables, overleaf

This is the code I have so far:

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \caption{The observation $(s_t)$ the DRL agent receives in the beginning of time t}
   \begin{tabular}{c|ccccc|ccccccccc}
    \hline
        & GS & JN J& MSFT & PG & XOM & M & Volume & Log Return & VIX & Adj. Close & 30-d SMA & 60-d SMA & $\Delta $30-d SMA & $\Delta$ 60-d SMA \\ %\hline
        & & & Covariance Matrix (252-days) & & & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
        GS & \Sigma_{1,1} & \Sigma_{1,2} & \Sigma_{1,3} & \Sigma_{1,4} & \Sigma_{1,5} & x& x_{1,7} & x_{1,8} &x  &x_{1,10} &x_{1,11}  &x_{1,12} &x_{1,13} & x_{1,14} \\ %\hline 
        JNJ & \Sigma_{2,1} & \Sigma_{2,2} & \Sigma_{2,3} & \Sigma_{2,4} & \Sigma_{2,5} & x& x_{2,7} & x_{2,8} &x  &x_{2,10} &x_{2,11}  &x_{2,12} &x_{2,13} & x_{2,14} \\ %\hline
        MSFT & \Sigma_{3,1} & \Sigma_{3,2} & \Sigma_{3,3} & \Sigma_{3,4} & \Sigma_{3,5} & x& x_{3,7} & x_{3,8} &x  &x_{3,10} &x_{3,11}  &x_{3,12} &x_{3,13} & x_{3,14} \\ %\hline
        PG & \Sigma_{4,1} & \Sigma_{4,2} & \Sigma_{4,3} & \Sigma_{4,4} & \Sigma_{4,5} & x& x_{4,7} & x_{4,8} &x  &x_{4,10} &x_{4,11}  &x_{4,12} &x_{4,13} & x_{4,14} \\ %\hline
        XOM & \Sigma_{5,1} & \Sigma_{5,2} & \Sigma_{5,3} & \Sigma_{5,4} & \Sigma_{5,5} & x& x_{5,7} & x_{5,8} &x  &x_{5,10} &x_{5,11}  &x_{5,12} &x_{5,13} & x_{5,14}\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}\\
```

And the table is supposed to look like this:[image]

Comment: The most pressing problem is that you mustn't use math commands like `_` outside of math mode. Everything further will depend on the page geometry of your document.

Comment: ... that being said, have a look at the `tabularray` package. It makes it easy to use custom line styles like your dashed vertical lines

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt, which you can tweak as need be, using the [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package.

You didn't give your document class or page dimensions. I set 1in margins and set the font size inside the table environment to `\scriptsize` to get it to fit. You might want to use a different font size depending on your page dimensions and/or rotate the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}% optional; changes font to more like image
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\newcommand{\x}{\mathrm{x}}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering\scriptsize
    
   \begin{tblr}{
        colspec = {Q[l]Q[c,$]Q[c,$]Q[c,$]Q[c,$]Q[c,$]Q[c,$]Q[c,$]Q[c,$]Q[c,$]Q[c,$]Q[c,$]Q[c,$]Q[c,$]Q[c,$]},
        % mostly centered (c) columns in math mode by default ($)
        hline{1,3,8} = {0.7pt,solid},% thicker horizontal lines above rows 1,3 and 8
        vline{2,7} = {0.5pt,dashed}% dashed vertical lines before columns 2 and 7
    }
        & \text{GS} & \text{JNJ} & \text{MSFT} & \text{PG} & \text{XOM} & \text{M} & \text{Volume} & \text{Log} & \text{VIX} & \text{Adj.} & \text{30-d} & \text{60-d} & \Delta \text{ 30-d} & \Delta \text{ 60-d} \\
        & \SetCell[c=5]{c,mode=text}{\fontsize{6}{6}\selectfont Covariance Matrix (252-days)} & & & & & & & \text{Return} & & \text{Close}  & \text{SMA} & \text{SMA}& \text{SMA}& \text{SMA}\\
        GS & \Sigma_{1,1} & \Sigma_{1,2} & \Sigma_{1,3} & \Sigma_{1,4} & \Sigma_{1,5} & \x& \x_{1,7} & \x_{1,8} &\x  &\x_{1,10} &\x_{1,11}  &\x_{1,12} &\x_{1,13} & \x_{1,14} \\
        JNJ & \Sigma_{2,1} & \Sigma_{2,2} & \Sigma_{2,3} & \Sigma_{2,4} & \Sigma_{2,5} & \x& \x_{2,7} & \x_{2,8} &\x  &\x_{2,10} &\x_{2,11}  &\x_{2,12} &\x_{2,13} & \x_{2,14} \\
        MSFT & \Sigma_{3,1} & \Sigma_{3,2} & \Sigma_{3,3} & \Sigma_{3,4} & \Sigma_{3,5} & \x& \x_{3,7} & \x_{3,8} &\x  &\x_{3,10} &\x_{3,11}  &\x_{3,12} &\x_{3,13} & \x_{3,14} \\
        PG & \Sigma_{4,1} & \Sigma_{4,2} & \Sigma_{4,3} & \Sigma_{4,4} & \Sigma_{4,5} & \x& \x_{4,7} & \x_{4,8} &\x  &\x_{4,10} &\x_{4,11}  &\x_{4,12} &\x_{4,13} & \x_{4,14} \\
        XOM & \Sigma_{5,1} & \Sigma_{5,2} & \Sigma_{5,3} & \Sigma_{5,4} & \Sigma_{5,5} & \x& \x_{5,7} & \x_{5,8} &\x  &\x_{5,10} &\x_{5,11}  &\x_{5,12} &\x_{5,13} & \x_{5,14}\\
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{The observation $(s_t)$ the DRL agent receives in the beginning of time $t$}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know what the "x"s mean, but I'm not sure my definition of `\x` which I inserted to make them upright in math mode is really what you want.

Comment: This is my page dimention: \geometry{left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, textwidth=16.4cm, top=3cm, textheight=25.2cm, bottom=2cm} and this is my document class: \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}.  When I opened a new project the table is working, however in my excising project is gives me an error is the \end{tblr} part.

Comment: @geo overleaf will keep the texlive version stable for existing projects. For the project, you will get the current version of texlive, including updates for tabularray. If you want to update your existing project, you can select a newer texlive version in the sidebar

Comment: @geo Without knowing more about the difference between the new document and your existing project, it's impossible for me to guess why it might not be working. Try samcarter's suggestion of updating the texlive version, but if that doesn't work, a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that produces the error would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that employs a `tabularx` environment in landscape format. Observe that I've placed the string "Covariance Matrix (252-days)" above rather than below the first horizontal line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx,amsmath,ragged2e,rotating}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % centered and automatic math mode 
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}{#1}}
\newcommand\mD[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X@{}}{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable} % switch to landscape mode & start a table env.
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 0pt

\caption{The observation $(s_t)$ the DRL agent receives at the beginning of time $t$}

\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l | *{5}{C} | *{9}{C} @{}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Covariance Matrix (252-days)} \\
\hline
& \text{GS} & \text{JN J} & \text{MSFT} & \text{PG}  & \text{XOM} 
& \mC{M} & \mC{Volume} & \mC{Log Return} & \mC{VIX} & \mC{Adj. Close} 
& \mC{30-d SMA} & \mC{60-d SMA} 
& \mC{$\Delta$~30-d SMA} & \mD{$\Delta$~60-d SMA} \\ 
\hline
 GS   & \Sigma_{1,1} & \Sigma_{1,2} & \Sigma_{1,3} & \Sigma_{1,4} & \Sigma_{1,5} & x & x_{1,7} & x_{1,8} & x & x_{1,10} & x_{1,11} & x_{1,12} & x_{1,13} & x_{1,14} \\ 
 JNJ  & \Sigma_{2,1} & \Sigma_{2,2} & \Sigma_{2,3} & \Sigma_{2,4} & \Sigma_{2,5} & x & x_{2,7} & x_{2,8} & x & x_{2,10} & x_{2,11} & x_{2,12} & x_{2,13} & x_{2,14} \\ 
 MSFT & \Sigma_{3,1} & \Sigma_{3,2} & \Sigma_{3,3} & \Sigma_{3,4} & \Sigma_{3,5} & x & x_{3,7} & x_{3,8} & x & x_{3,10} & x_{3,11} & x_{3,12} & x_{3,13} & x_{3,14} \\ 
 PG   & \Sigma_{4,1} & \Sigma_{4,2} & \Sigma_{4,3} & \Sigma_{4,4} & \Sigma_{4,5} & x & x_{4,7} & x_{4,8} & x & x_{4,10} & x_{4,11} & x_{4,12} & x_{4,13} & x_{4,14} \\ 
 XOM  & \Sigma_{5,1} & \Sigma_{5,2} & \Sigma_{5,3} & \Sigma_{5,4} & \Sigma_{5,5} & x & x_{5,7} & x_{5,8} & x & x_{5,10} & x_{5,11} & x_{5,12} &x_{5,13} & x_{5,14}\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```